# How does the shell output line separator fail to get reset?

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, vim, zsh

I execute an incorrect command over ssh:

```
watch /bin/df | grep _23
```

Now I execute a command like `env` and get this:

```
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.3.4
                         LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
                                           LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
                                                               LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                                     LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                                                            LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                                                                                   LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                                                                                                         LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                                                                                                                            LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
                                                                SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh                                                                                                                                                                        SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/26
   TERM=xterm-256color
                      DISPLAY=localhost:16.0
                                            XDG_SESSION_ID=18040
                                                                XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
                                                                                              SHLVL=1
```

It looks like the output line separator is a line feed but not carriage return.

But I'm not sure it only happens over ssh. I think I've seen this behavior after using `vim` too.

Why does this happen and what is the minimal way to reset it? I usually run `source ~/.zshrc` but that is overkill.

Comment: While not a direct answer, have you tried running the reset command? Many times I've had the console output get all janky and reset generally fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) that Unix, Linux, and other Unix-like systems
use a single character to represent the end of a line of text (EOL). 
This character is called Newline and is often represented as `\n`. 
This is somewhat confusing, as most software terminals (e.g., `xterm`)
and hardware teletypes require two control characters
to advance to a new line: a Carriage Return (CR)
to move the cursor (or print head) to the left margin,
and a Line Feed (LF) to move the cursor down one line
without moving horizontally (or scroll the window up, or roll the paper up). 
(The fact that Newline and LF are numerically the same byte value
adds to the confusion.)

Unix-like systems handle this by translating `\n` to CR + LF on output
in the TTY driver. 
However, you might not always want that to happen. 
In particular, you don’t want it to happen
if you are connecting to a non-Unix system via ssh. 
And `vim` doesn’t want it to happen;
it likes to be able to use Newline as Cursor Down. 
So that behavior is optional, and programs like ssh and `vim` disable it. 
(They should re-enable it upon exit,
but sometimes things don’t work correctly,
e.g., if a program gets interrupted.)

Like most TTY driver options, this is controlled by `stty`. 
The option is called `onlcr`, which stands for

    on
    **O**
    utput,
    when you see a
    **N**
    ew
    **L**
    ine, also output a
    **CR**

If you do `stty -a` (to see **a**ll the stty settings), you’ll see `onlcr`
(it may be near the beginning of the second-to-last line). 
If you do `stty -a` when you’re in the weird state,
you’ll see `-onlcr`, indicating that the option is turned off.

The simple fix for this specific problem
is to type `stty onlcr` to turn the option back on. 
But that’s an obscure initialism that may be hard to remember. 
Also, if the program (e.g., ssh or `vim`) has messed with stty settings,
it may have messed with other ones that are not as obvious. 
There’s an easy-to-remember command
to set all the stty settings back to normal values; it is

```
stty sane
```

As [jhufford points out](https://superuser.com/q/1650758/150988#comment2525306_1650758),
some systems have a `reset` command that also does this.

Comment: Very nice detailed answer!

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'll be referring to this over and over in future. I'll create a script called `~/bin/newline_fix.sh` so I don't have to remember the right commands.